# c# simple key press detection

Tags: c#, key, detect

I want to detect (as simple as posible) the "ctrl+o" keys and then show up a message. 
I tried: 
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981024/trying-to-detect-keypress)

and other 4 links, I cannot show you. Please help.

Comment: I'm assuming this is WPF based on your links?

Comment: [enter link description here][1]

didn't worked. I don't know why...

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705428/test-if-the-ctrl-key-is-down-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "O")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ctrl + o pressed");
    }
}
```