# how to detect key pressed in game with C#

Tags: c#

How can I detect if a key was pressed in a game (league of legends) using C#?

I used to do that with AHK with ease but I want to move to c# since I m studying it these days.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

My friend implemented a thread level mouse/keyboard hook.

[image]

Just install the Nuget package and give me some feedback.

```
Install-Package -IncludePrerelease Winook
```

Example:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("LeagueOfLegendProcessName");
_process = processes.FirstOrDefault();
if (_process == null)
{
    return;
}

_keyboardHook = new KeyboardHook(_process.Id);
_keyboardHook.MessageReceived += KeyboardHook_MessageReceived;

...

private void KeyboardHook_MessageReceived(object sender, KeyboardMessageEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Keyboard Virtual Key Code: {e.VirtualKeyCode}; Flags: {e.Flags:x}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [SetWindowsHookExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) it will let you hook to mouse and kb events and look into [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/) to learn how to do it.

Comment: any tutoriels to follow cuz I think I got lost ngl

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should always search in the documentations and read them carefully.

Bellow is an example of how to do it based on Microsoft documentation

```
// Uses the Keyboard.IsKeyDown to determine if a key is down.
// e is an instance of KeyEventArgs.
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Return))
{
    btnIsDown.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
else
{
    btnIsDown.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
}
```

Don't forget to import 'System.Windows.Input' namespace.

Follow the [link 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown?view=netcore-3.1) and [Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netcore-3.1) for more info.

Edit:
This question is answered in this link: [Trying to detect keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981024/trying-to-detect-keypress)

Comment: oh thanks for the answer but that will work only if I m on the form , but what if I were in a game ?

Comment: The code snippet I posted wouldn't matter where are you using it. It  is not for form. Anywhere you can run this code, it should work.